# PHP AdobeSign API :: transientDocuments with OAuth2.0

Tags: php, echosign

I am using `PHP OAuth2.0 Adobesign API` for sending pdf to user for e-signature purpose.

I successfully generate auth token and refresh token by following basic OAuth2 steps.

Now I am facing issue while trying to send pdf transientDocuments using curl code.  Below is my sample code:

```
define("CALLBACK_URL", "https://www.getdadstrong.com/vipin/test.php");
define("AUTH_URL", "https://api.in1.echosign.com/api/rest/v6/transientDocuments");
define("ACCESS_TOKEN_URL", "http://api.in1.echosign.com/oauth/token");
define("CLIENT_ID", "MY_CLIENT_ID");
define("CLIENT_SECRET", "MY_CLIENT_SECRET");
define("SCOPE", "agreement_send:account"); // optional


function getToken(){

 $curlFILE = curl_init();
 $params = array(
    CURLOPT_URL =>  AUTH_URL,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_NOBODY => false, 

    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Bearer MY_SECURE_TOKEN", 
      "cache-control: no-cache",
      "content-type: multipart/form-data",
      "Content-Disposition: form-data; name='file'; filename='MyPDF.pdf'",
    ),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array (
                // 'filename' => new CURLFile('./MyPDF.pdf') 
                'filename' => new CURLFile('./MyPDF.pdf','application/pdf','MyFile') 
        ),
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE 
  );

    curl_setopt_array($curlFILE, $params);
    $response = curl_exec($curlFILE);


    curl_close($curlFILE);
    $err = curl_error($curlFILE);
    if ($err) {
        echo "<br/> cURL Error #01: " . $err;
    } 
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($err);  
    var_dump($response);  
    echo '<pre>';

  }
getToken();
```

Output:

```
{
    "code": "NO_FILE_CONTENT",
    "message": "Must provide file body"
}
```

Comment: is the path `./` to the file correct and does the file actually exist?

Comment: Yes, File is really exist in same folder

Comment: try using the actual full path, ie: `__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'mypdf.pdf'` etc

Comment: Yes, I try it..  getting same error.  I think we need to send pdf by some other format to this API like binary or base_encode.  I also try this with fopen('MyPDF.pdf','r') to read file but not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I come to know Adobe Esign with V6 having some issue with this method.  So I switch to V5 and make some little modification in my code.  It is working for me.

```
<?php
define("AUTH_URL", "https://api.na2.echosign.com/api/rest/v5/transientDocuments");

$url = AUTH_URL;
$header =array(
        "Authorization: Bearer 3AAAB6hBTt666543359kgBzroaNxqyezwBRdsdsdssssssssss6767gGy7CNdERHxqz1r5lOzmyxI7hfQ22zsyCDvnG_HRc8m9B7UBRJuGy", 
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "content-type: multipart/form-data",
        "Content-Disposition: form-data; name='File'; filename='MyPDF.pdf'",
    );

$filePath= '@'.file_get_contents('MyPDF.pdf');
$fields = array('File' => $filePath,'Mime-Type' => 'application/pdf', 'File-Name' => 'MyPDF.pdf');

$resource = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($resource, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $fields,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header
));


$res = curl_exec($resource);
$result = json_decode($res,true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
curl_close($resource);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [transientDocumentId] => 3AA777777777777gwxctQX8kTYj2e3Esgc5_HbvKgKK_oaIccNqr2JwWJK8bUXn779OMvyFMJG2VONbbbMqO-bo_GoKJP-wfYszcQtg7tbJ8sc8YxTwQPm3kV77777ThgQy5ZoeHb_km-zmitgdSkf7sLYp0vCO8CAbvYQVzd3OpU6zJ-Mv54VoVKvsYUFsfhfhgK]epKpCHnvKWvn37fghfg777876rV2QYyh9bkApotXvSzxndXNQbUTmAcpP1Jq-WlXsVdGleKjHoEMoDgfhfghIOYQFxy5eeOtctqwtxC9MUWjioGV6FW6ZtoGm0ijqGU*
)
```

Comment: Hi I use your code and it work great. i get transientDocumentId response with a pdf test purpose only.....now i don't understand.... what is the use of this "transientDocumentId" string? My goal is to send a clean PDF to a widget and the destinatary can sign it and get it back.....

Comment: Thank you, @hardeep-singh! It is working for me. My problem was in Drupal 8, I try using Drupal's HTTPClient with "multipart" etc. configs, but the Adobe Sign API persisted in not seeing my attached PDF file ... So, CURL solution is working in my Drupal.

Comment: BTW: if I try use **CurlFile()** to get a file content:
`$file_contents = new \CurlFile('public://testdoc-20201025.pdf', 'application/pdf', 'testdoc-20201025.pdf');`

it is NOT working also. `$filePath= '@'.file_get_contents('MyPDF.pdf');` was actual solution in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had a little play in some free time and the following seemed to work on my test system. The function targets a very simple php endpoint rather than a remote url/api endpoint.

```
$file=sprintf('%s%slamb_vindaloo.pdf', __DIR__, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );



define( 'BEARER_TOKEN', '74e793ea86b6e06d5d971454a955c48012a422d7694d3463c23f69ef758f62db' );
define( 'AUTH_URL', 'https://sentinel/demo/stack/pdf-receiver.php' );
define( 'CA_CERTIFICATE', 'c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem' );



function getToken( $file=false ){
    if( !$file )return;
    $curl = curl_init();
    $params = array(
        CURLOPT_URL =>  AUTH_URL,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_NOBODY => false, 

        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            sprintf( "Authorization: Bearer %s", BEARER_TOKEN ), 
            "Cache-Control: no-cache",
            "Content-Type: application/octet-stream",   #   <----- set the content-type
            sprintf("Content-Disposition: form-data; name='file'; filename='%s'", $file ),
        ),

        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array (
            'filename'  =>  new CURLFile( $file, mime_content_type( $file ), pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_FILENAME ) ) 
        ),

        CURLOPT_CAINFO  =>  CA_CERTIFICATE,     #   <------ if the endpoint is SSL it is advisable to use a valid cacert.pem file!!
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,        #   <------ if possible set this to true
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2             #   <------ true/false are not options for this
    );
    curl_setopt_array( $curl, $params );
    /*
        Return an object with the various return values
        rather than doing any printing from within the 
        function
    */
    $res=(object)array(
        'response'  =>  curl_exec( $curl ),
        'info'      =>  (object)curl_getinfo( $curl ),
        'errors'    =>  curl_error( $curl )
    );
    curl_close( $curl );
    return $res;
}   

/* call the function */
$results=getToken( $file );

/* process the response accordingly */
if( $results->info->http_code==200 ){
    printf('<pre>%s</pre>', $results->response );
}
```

The simple PHP endpoint is:

```
<?php
    #
    #   PDF File Receiver for curlFile Tests....
    #
    $data=file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
    echo base64_encode( $data );
?>
```

The response, to highlight success was as follows:

```
LS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS02NGQ5ZGYyYTE3ZmE1MGNkDQpDb250ZW50LURpc3Bvc...etc etc
```